# Convert .rtf file to sting output - how to remove /par from string output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

```
with open('myfile.rtf', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()
print(text)
```

I have tried this code but the problem it has, is there is a `\par` printed for every <kbd>Enter</kbd> pressed during the data entry in the `.rtf` file. Can someone please help me remove the `'\par'` from the string output?

Comment: RTF files can have lots more tags than that.  You might want to look into the `read_rtf` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('myfile.rtf', 'r') as file:
      text = file.read()
from striprtf.striprtf import rtf_to_text
rtf = text
text1 = rtf_to_text(rtf)
print(text1)
```

In terminal please use this code `pip install striprtf` before executing the above code

With this code you can also take file with `.rtf` extension and produce an `str` output